# Display suite extra expert mode field classes not working on entity form fields

Tags: display-suite

I'm using display suite extra and trying to ad classes to fields via expert mode, but it's not working, I tried both teaser and full content, am I missing something here?

Using boostrap theme and this works with all content items and fields, but not with entity forms, any idea?

Using D7 with boostrap theme.

[image]

Comment: flush the cache once and check

Comment: Yes, I did that of course! Numerous times;)